# My topdomain traffic comes in "direct traffic" under Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, web-analytics

I am currently working on an ecommerce website that is hosted under the subdomain : *sales.product.company.com/store* under https (let's call it B) and one of my main source of traffic comes from a page of the topdomain website : *www.company.com/service/something* which is under http (let's call it A)

These pages have differents GA Accounts and I only have the possibility to configure the one from the ecommerce website.

---

My problem is that the traffic coming from A to B is tracked by GA as "direct" traffic, which I think is surprising, I would like to see it as referral. I have tried several things but none of them are working ... Here are some inputs :

- I use Google Tag Manager in B.
- The link from A to B opens B in a new tab
- I use the Chrome GA Debug extension, and I see the website A as referrer in the debug report (console)
- I tried to set cookieDomain to *company.com* but it did not change anything.

May be I am missing something (i am still a beginer on GA). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into the referral exclusion list (property settings/tracking info), most likely your domain is listed there.

Comment: Yes that was the trick ! Thank you very much !